# User prompted odd or even lines from a text file

Tags: python

I need to write a program that asks the user for the name of a text file and to pick either "odd" or "even". Then the program would read this file and prints only odd or even numbered lines of the input file's contents, depending on which the user picks (presume the first line is line 1).
This is the code I have so far:

```
fileOne = open(input (str("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:" )), "r")

odd_even = input(str("Would you like the line odd or even?: "))
for line in fileOne:
    count = 0
    if odd_even == "even" or "Even":
        if count % 2 == 0:
        print(line)
    elif odd_even == "odd" or "Odd":
        if count % 2 == 1:
        print(line)
```

Comment: this is not how "or" works in python, "a == b or c" is actually "(a == b) or c", you probably want "(a==b) or (a==c)" instead

Answer (score 0):

You should make compare in next way:

```
if odd_even == "even" or odd_even == "Even":
```

Or better:

```
if odd_even in ["even", "Even"]:
```

Or even:

```
if odd_even.lower() == "even":
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @lejlot in comments Problem with your code is the improper `or` statement.

Your first if condition will always yields true.

```
if odd_even == "even" or "Even":
```

These are basically two conditions joined by `or`. Interpreted as

```
odd_even == "even"
```

and

```
"Even"
```

No matter what the results are of first condition, second condition will make the entire statement true because `X or True` is always `True` and in Python `"Even"` is `True` because `bool("Even")` is `True`.

Further, Python respects indentation and you need to properly indent your code to make that work.

```
fileOne = open(input (str("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:" )), "r")


odd_even = input(str("Would you like the line odd or even?: "))
for line in fileOne:
    count = 0
    if odd_even == "even" or odd_even == "Even":
        if count % 2 == 0:
        print(line)
    elif odd_even == "odd" or odd_even == "Odd":
        if count % 2 == 1:
        print(line)
```

PS: @MakeTips has better suggestion regarding improving your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the value of `odd_even` for every line; check it *once* to determine what `count %2` should be compared to.

```
fname = input("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open: ")
odd_even = input("Would you like the even or odd lines? ")
odd_even = 0 if odd_even.lower() == "even" else 1
with open(fname) as fileOne:
    for count, line in enumerate(fileOne):
        if count % 2 == odd_even:
            print(line)
```

Note:

1. Use a `with` statement to ensure that the input file is properly closed when you are done with it.
2. Use the `lower` method to "normalize" the value, allowing for a single comparison.
3. Use `enumerate` to get a line number with each line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

besides the `or` thing people have mentioned, you also need to change the way you hadle your `count` variable. the following will actually "check which line you're on", with the 1st line as line 1.

```
count = 0
for line in fileOne:
    count += 1
    #rest of code
```